# How to find a field name/column name of a field in database where I have only the label of that field?

Tags: views, entities, database

I am working on an integration part with drupal framework. Here it's hard to  find the table names of the field which is present in the view as I know only the field label name.

Is there any way to sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can derive the database table name by the host entity and the field name. The name schema is `ENTITYTYPE__FIELDNAME`

Views don't directly show the field name, but you can look at the entity's "Manage field" page to get the field name by label. (e.g. for nodes `/admin/structure/types/manage/BUNDLENAME/fields`)

Examples:

```
node__body
node__field_image
users__field_whatsapp
taxonomy_term__field_text
```

Exception:
Some special fields (like `title` or `created`) are stored as a column on the base table of an entity. Base tables follow the schema `ENTITYTYPE_field_data`, e.g.

```
node_field_data
users_field_data
taxonomy_term_field_data
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I am having a field label called summary in the products details page. How to find that field name and it's stored table in database?

Comment: Summary is not a real field, it is the short version of the body field (like an URL field has a title and URL column). Look in the node__body table

Comment: Can you tell me where does the manufacturers list stored in database?